# Filtering out all the rows before "X" happens

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dplyr

I have a list of data frames and I'm trying to filter out all the rows before certain characters appear in the column Z (all the rows before that are "NA"). I tried the code

```
for(i in 1:length(list_of_df)){
list_of_df[[i]] <- list_of_df[[i]] %>% dplyr::slice(which.max(list_of_df[[i]]$Z == "NA")) : n()
}
```

but for some reason I get

```
Error in UseMethod("slice") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

What's going on here and how could I fix the problem?

Comment: Don't use `data$column` inside `dplyr` verbs. You're piping the data frame in, you don't need to respecify it. And use `is.na()` to test if something is `NA`. Try `slice(which.max(is.na(Z)):n())`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? For instance one dataframe, `dput(head(list_of_df[[1]], 20))`?

Comment: If you need more help, please share a little bit of sample data. We don't need a list of data frames, just one or two small examples.

Comment: @GregorThomas Ahh yes, this worked, thank you! Not too familiar with piping and R as a whole yet, so this clarified the problem. Also, instead of which.max apparently I was suppose to use which.min to filter out those na-values from the beginning!